# How to manipulate `dot` graph in python

Tags: python, graph, nlp, dot

Stanford dependency parser generates a graph in `dot` format, which looks something like this.

Sentence => "John is a Computer Scientist"

```
digraph G{
edge [dir=forward]
node [shape=plaintext]

0 [label="0 (None)"]
0 -> 5 [label="root"]
1 [label="1 (John)"]
2 [label="2 (is)"]
3 [label="3 (a)"]
4 [label="4 (Computer)"]
5 [label="5 (Scientist)"]
5 -> 2 [label="cop"]
5 -> 4 [label="compound"]
5 -> 3 [label="det"]
5 -> 1 [label="nsubj"]
}
```

I want to find terms like `Computer` and `Scientist` and combine them into one. I already have code that gives me which terms to be combined. However I am not able to find such terms in graph, and combine to generate a `dot` format output. I looked at `Graphviz` which can create new graph and plot and save files, but I could not find a way to search for nodes and combine them. How should I do this?

PS : I looked at [iGraph](http://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html), however, it does not support reading `dot` format. I also found `graph-tools`, which I think is a very heavy utility for some simple task like this. (One of its dependency itself is about 200MB). Even in NetworkX documentation, I could not any method to search a node with a particular label.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are looking for. If you want to import a dot file to a graph, take a look at NetworkX, especially [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/drawing.html?highlight=dot#module-networkx.drawing.nx_pydot).

Comment: As I said, I want to find specific terms from my graph, in this case, a node containing "Computer", and modify them. I have already imported dot using Graphviz, however, using graphviz I am not able to modify the graph.

Comment: With NetworkX and PyDot, you can read dot files like this: `G = nx.read_dot(myfile)`. Combining nodes can then e.g. be done like this: `G2 = nx.contracted_nodes(G, 'computer', 'scientist')`.

Comment: Still, you should put the code you used until now, or tell us why you are not "able to modify the graph". I get you problem but I need some technical details.